# remote-exec provisioner in terraform gives timeout

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to spin up an EC2 instance using an ubuntu image. I want to provide ssh access to the instance, install and run the apache server, and open up port 80, all through terraform.

I have the following code for `remote-exec` for my EC2

```
provisioner "remote-exec" {
  inline = [
    "sudo apt update -y",
    "sudo apt upgrade -y",
    "sudo apt install apache2 -y",
    "sudo systemctl status apache2"
  ]
}
```

however, **after all commands are executed successfully** i.e. systemctl shows the correct response, my prompt hangs at aws_instance.web_server_instance: Still creating...

[image: console output]

my full code

```
terraform {
  required_version = "~> 1.1.5"

  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "3.74.1"
    }

    local = {
      source  = "hashicorp/local"
      version = "2.1.0"
    }

    tls = {
      source  = "hashicorp/tls"
      version = "3.1.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "aws" {
  profile = "terraform"
  region  = "us-east-1"
}

locals {
  application_name = "web_server"
}



# ssh key

resource "tls_private_key" "web_server_key_pair_gen" {
  algorithm = "RSA"
}

resource "local_file" "web_server_private_key" {
  content  = tls_private_key.web_server_key_pair_gen.private_key_pem
  filename = "${local.application_name}_private_key.pem"
}

resource "aws_key_pair" "web_server_public_key" {
  key_name   = "${local.application_name}_public_key"
  public_key = tls_private_key.web_server_key_pair_gen.public_key_openssh
}



# security group

resource "aws_security_group" "web_server_security_group" {
  name = "${local.application_name}_security_group"

  dynamic "ingress" {
    for_each = [
      { port = 22, description = "ssh" },
      { port = 80, description = "http" },
    ]
    content {
      description      = ingress.value.description
      from_port        = ingress.value.port
      to_port          = ingress.value.port
      protocol         = "tcp"
      cidr_blocks      = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
      ipv6_cidr_blocks = []
      prefix_list_ids  = []
      security_groups  = []
      self             = false
    }
  }

  egress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  tags = {
    Name = "${local.application_name}_security_group"
  }
}



# ami lookup

data "aws_ami" "ubuntu" {
  most_recent = true

  filter {
    name   = "name"
    values = ["ubuntu/images/hvm-ssd/ubuntu-focal-20.04-amd64-server-*"]
  }

  filter {
    name   = "virtualization-type"
    values = ["hvm"]
  }

  owners = ["099720109477"]
}



# ec2 instance

resource "aws_instance" "web_server_instance" {
  ami                         = data.aws_ami.ubuntu.id
  instance_type               = "t2.micro"
  vpc_security_group_ids      = [aws_security_group.web_server_security_group.id]
  key_name                    = aws_key_pair.web_server_public_key.key_name
  associate_public_ip_address = true

  connection {
    user        = "ubuntu"
    private_key = tls_private_key.web_server_key_pair_gen.private_key_pem
    host        = self.public_ip
  }

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "chmod 600 ${local_file.web_server_private_key.filename}"
  }

  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [
      "sudo apt update -y",
      "sudo apt upgrade -y",
      "sudo apt install apache2 -y",
      "sudo systemctl status apache2"
    ]
  }

  tags = {
    Name = "${local.application_name}_instance"
  }
}

output "server_public_ip" {
  value = aws_instance.web_server_instance.public_ip
}
```

Comment: Why are you using remote-exec instead of a user data cloud-init script?

Comment: hey @MarkB, thanks for the reply. I started learning terraform today morning and am just trying things out, for educational purpose.

Comment: Remote provisioners are generally considered a "last resort" in Terraform. AWS EC2 provides a method of initializing a server, through user data scripts, which is going to be much more reliable.

Comment: Some more information on the provisioner usage tradeoffs and some other options to consider is in the official documentation section [Provisioners are a Last Resort](https://www.terraform.io/language/resources/provisioners/syntax#provisioners-are-a-last-resort). In particular, see _Passing data into virtual machines and other compute resources_ for this use-case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you probably should follow advice given in comments, your specific case is probably due to systemctl output being piped through the pager (less), so it waits to receive `q` to quit.

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/systemctl.1.html:

> ```
>    $SYSTEMD_PAGER
>        Pager to use when --no-pager is not given; overrides $PAGER.
>        If neither $SYSTEMD_PAGER nor $PAGER are set, a set of
>        well-known pager implementations are tried in turn, including
>        less(1) and more(1), until one is found. If no pager
>        implementation is discovered no pager is invoked. Setting
>        this environment variable to an empty string or the value
>        "cat" is equivalent to passing --no-pager.
> ```

Using `--no-pager` option should help here.